# ora-29833 indextype does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g, ddl

Creating index for the wild card search.

While executing the below script in oracle 10g

```
CREATE INDEX sampletexttext_idx ON tablename(columnname)
INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context parameters ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE');
```

It throws the exception below:

> ora-29833 indextype does not exist

I tried `basic_wordlist` also. It's not working

Can anyone suggest to do the best way for creating index for wildcard search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems something incomplete when you created it. Please see below how to do that:

--- create a sample table

```
drop table quick ;
create table quick 
  ( 
    quick_id number primary key, 
    text      varchar(80) 
  );
```

--- insert a row with 10 expansions for 'tire%'

```
insert into quick ( quick_id, text ) 
  values ( 1, 'tire tirea tireb tirec tired tiree tiref tireg tireh tirei 
tirej') ;
commit;
```

--- create an index using wildcard_maxterms=100

```
begin 
    Ctx_Ddl.Create_Preference('wildcard_pref', 'BASIC_WORDLIST'); 
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('wildcard_pref', 'wildcard_maxterms', 100) ;
end; 
/
create index wildcard_idx on quick(text)
    indextype is ctxsys.context 
    parameters ('Wordlist wildcard_pref') ;
```

--- query on 'tire%' - should work fine

```
select quick_id from quick
  where contains ( text, 'tire%' ) > 0;

drop table quick ;
```

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/cdatadi6.htm